# vb.net using cefsharp browser how to invoke click for element that without ID

Tags: javascript, vb.net, invoke, cefsharp

using vb.net vs2019
using cefsharp to invoke a sign in button that do not have ID in element
Looking around google do not have solution.

website
https://kumoten.com/customer/login

element for "sign in" button

Sign In

Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

```
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://kumoten.com/customer/login") With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim jsScript As String = <js><![CDATA[document.all("username").value ="xxxxxxx"; document.all("password").value ="xxxxxxx";]]></js>.Value
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScript)

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = browser.ExcuteScriptAsync.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

i manage to key in the user name and password. but i failed to invoke click for sign in button because it do not have the ID.

expected to sign in and click automatic after press "vb button1"

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to see what data is sent to the server during a login, and imitate that (with a webclient/httpclient)

Comment: sorry. i not understand. i inspect element. the only thing i can see is "type" and "class" and those inrelevant information. imitate with webclient?

Comment: Why are type and class irrelevant? If there is only one submit button you can easily get it by type, same goes for class

Comment: <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary pull-right" style="width: 100%; border-radius:5px; padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom:9px; border: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232); font-size:16px !important;">
Sign In
</button>

Comment: above is the inspect element for sign in button. how to autoclick by using chromium vb.net. can i have sample of coding?